# How do I find the second best in the array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

I have an array called players. I am trying to find what the top seven players in the array are based on overall. I have a function to find the best player, but I need help on how to make it where I can find the second best and so on. Please help! Thank you in advance. Here is the code:

```
<script>
            var players = [
                {name: "Pat Moran", overall: 67, position: "AP"},
                {name: "Peter Webb", overall: 81, position: "AP"},
                {name: "Ramiro Ramirez", overall: 74, position: "AP"},
                {name: "Manuel Knight", overall: 68, position: "RP"},
                {name: "Allan Alexander", overall: 71, position: "RP"},
                {name: "Gerald Bowman", overall: 81, position: "RP"},
                {name: "Owen Day", overall: 78, position: 3},
                {name: "Jean Ford", overall: 70, position: 3},
                {name: "Guy Curtis", overall: 59, position: 3},
                {name: "Dallas Diaz", overall: 68, position: 4},
                {name: "Jesus Brooks", overall: 70, position: 4},
                {name: "Todd Beck", overall: 76, position: 4},
                {name: "Steve Cortez", overall: 66, position: 5},
                {name: "Toby Caldwell", overall: 64, position: 5},
                {name: "Seth Bradley", overall: 73, position: 5},
                {name: "Lawrence McCarthy", overall: 67, position: 6},
                {name: "Gerardo Marsh", overall: 77, position: 6},
                {name: "Alvin Nash", overall: 78, position: 6}
            ];

            function findBestPlayer() {
                var bestSoFar = 0;
                var bestPlayer;
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    if (players[i].overall > bestSoFar) {
                        bestPlayer = players[i];
                        bestSoFar = players[i].overall;
                    }
                }
                return bestPlayer;
            }

            var bestPlayer = findBestPlayer();

            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = bestPlayer.name;
            document.getElementById("p1ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayer.overall;
            document.getElementById("p1pos").innerHTML = bestPlayer.position;
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean without sorting?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can be used to check only with the available players.

You can sort using a comparator function.

```js
function comp(b, a) {
  return a.overall - b.overall;
}
var players = [{
  name: "Pat Moran",
  overall: 67,
  position: "AP",
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Peter Webb",
  overall: 81,
  position: "AP",
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Ramiro Ramirez",
  overall: 74,
  position: "AP",
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Manuel Knight",
  overall: 68,
  position: "RP",
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Allan Alexander",
  overall: 71,
  position: "RP",
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Gerald Bowman",
  overall: 81,
  position: "RP",
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Owen Day",
  overall: 78,
  position: 3,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Jean Ford",
  overall: 70,
  position: 3,
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Guy Curtis",
  overall: 59,
  position: 3,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Dallas Diaz",
  overall: 68,
  position: 4,
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Jesus Brooks",
  overall: 70,
  position: 4,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Todd Beck",
  overall: 76,
  position: 4,
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Steve Cortez",
  overall: 66,
  position: 5,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Toby Caldwell",
  overall: 64,
  position: 5,
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Seth Bradley",
  overall: 73,
  position: 5,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Lawrence McCarthy",
  overall: 67,
  position: 6,
  available: false
}, {
  name: "Gerardo Marsh",
  overall: 77,
  position: 6,
  available: true
}, {
  name: "Alvin Nash",
  overall: 78,
  position: 6,
  available: false
}];

function checkAvailabilty(obj) {
  return !!obj.available;
}

var findBestPlayer = (function(arr) {
  // a copy of the original data is made.
  var data = arr.slice(0);
  // sort the data with a comparator function
  data.sort(comp);
  // filter out the unavailable players.
  data = data.filter(checkAvailabilty);
  return function(index) {
    return data[index];
  }
})(players);
// best player.
console.log('best available player: ', findBestPlayer(0));
// second best player.
console.log('second best available player: ', findBestPlayer(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I am going to add a variable to each player called "available". If available is false, I want it to not be included into the function. Therefore, it will disappear from the screen, and the next best player will show up. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hey @DallasWhite Absolutely thats possible. You can use array.filter to attain it. Please check the updated answer sir.

Comment: @DallasWhite You can accept the answer if it solves your problem or let us know if you need more modifications. Thanks in advance for it. :D

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question about adding available property, which you can filter on in the DOM to hide. You can chain a map function to the sort to return a sorted array with available property added.

```
function comp (b,a) {
  return a.overall - b.overall;
}
var players = [
    {name: "Pat Moran", overall: 67, position: "AP"},
    {name: "Peter Webb", overall: 81, position: "AP"},
    {name: "Ramiro Ramirez", overall: 74, position: "AP"},
    {name: "Manuel Knight", overall: 68, position: "RP"},
    {name: "Allan Alexander", overall: 71, position: "RP"},
    {name: "Gerald Bowman", overall: 81, position: "RP"},
    {name: "Owen Day", overall: 78, position: 3},
    {name: "Jean Ford", overall: 70, position: 3},
    {name: "Guy Curtis", overall: 59, position: 3},
    {name: "Dallas Diaz", overall: 68, position: 4},
    {name: "Jesus Brooks", overall: 70, position: 4},
    {name: "Todd Beck", overall: 76, position: 4},
    {name: "Steve Cortez", overall: 66, position: 5},
    {name: "Toby Caldwell", overall: 64, position: 5},
    {name: "Seth Bradley", overall: 73, position: 5},
    {name: "Lawrence McCarthy", overall: 67, position: 6}
    {name: "Gerardo Marsh", overall: 77, position: 6},
    {name: "Alvin Nash", overall: 78, position: 6}
];

var findBestPlayer = players.sort(comp).map(function(player, index){
  player.available = index <= 6 ? true : false
  return player
})

// best player.
console.log(findBestPlayer[0]);

// second best player.
console.log(findBestPlayer[1]);
```